# What is faster? File_exist or MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, innodb

Users in my webgame are having certain player information cached in the $_SESSION of PHP.
Each time they load the game it checks if the session exists, if not they get the player information from a MySQL database and then it gets stored in the $_SESSION.

Now my problem is, what if the player information gets updated by another process or player? They can't update the $_SESSION cache of the other player.

I know memcached is most probably the solution for this, but I'm not sure if I should take the time for something like this. $_SESSION cache is doing well for me, except for this.

- I was thinking about creating a MySQL table for it which get read at every request and if there's a record for the player that it recreates the cache.
- One other solution would be to create a file in a directory with the id of the player in the name of the file. Every request PHP will check with `file_exist` if it should clear the cache or not.

What would you guys do? It gets executed every request so it's pretty important to get this optimized.

Comment: Will go for database option, Speed wise there wont be alot of difference with a good database schema. But its not just about speed, its about better management aswell

Comment: If it's not extremely exceptional case, You always go for a database. In real world RMDB maybe faster than flat file(if the data already has been loaded to the memory or full table fit to the available memory.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a design standpoint alone I'd avoid the file_exists and directory approach.  Sure 'file_exists' is fast, but it won't scale well... What happens if a use changes their name?

If you're using APC (and you should) you could APC's user memory cache.  As long as  you're on a single server it should give you similar performance benifits as memcached without the need for a separate memory caching server process.  If a user entry changes frequently, you could run into fragmemntation issues with APC though.  In that case, time to bite the bullet and go with memcached--you can even store your session data in memcached for a performance boost.

Also, neither APC or your file_exists solution will scale to multiple load balanced servers--you'd need a DB solution or memcached for that.

Comment: From their homepage: "Use APC for caches that do not change often", the player information actually changes quite a lot since it also contains game stats from the player. Would it still be useful?

Comment: @Martin you could run into fragmentation issues with heavy changes to user caching in APC.  In that case, you're best bet is Memcached.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I might look into Memcached a bit better.

Comment: @Martin don't be turned off of memcached--it's easier than it looks.  If you're using a framework, most of them have helper cache libraries to connect to memcached backends.  PHP also has a memcached library you can use if you're not in a framework.  Most the work is just installing the memcached server and setting it up to run as it's own process.

Comment: @Martin  Also, make sure you look into memcached not memcache.  Both exists as php modules and are 2 different types of memcache server.

Comment: I'm not using any framework and I don't think the installing part is very hard, but I don't know if it's worth the effort. $_SESSION is working fine for me except for this thing which shouldn't be happening a lot either.. :P

Comment: @Martin Another big boon from using memcached is you can also use it for your session store instead of file based sessions--this will be a performance improvement.

Comment: Then I'll probably go Memcached.. :) Thanks a lot for all the explaining.

Answer (score 1):

The way you exposed it, is not about how fast is one vs the other, the SESSION approach is just not valid because of your concurrency issue.

If your data can change concurrently, then your data storage needs to be able to handle that concurrency and whatever caching layer you want to use needs to behave accordingly to the nature of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about cache, and you dont want to install memcache(d), you can go with a mysql table in memory. It is not as fast as memcached, but still a fine solution. And make sure to create proper indexes on all your tables (maybe that is the better solution, no cache, just select it from your table).

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```